What is the relevance of the usage ' the fire ' in Gen 22:6?
We read in Gen 22:6 (KJV):

And Abraham took the wood of the burnt offering, and laid it upon Isaac his son; and he took the fire in his hand, and a knife; and they went both of them together.

< 'Fire' per se, does not require to be prefixed with the definitive article ''the' unless preceded by a specific mention. Of course, Abraham had been asked to make a burnt offering. Is it possible that he kept a fire burning in his tent for the exclusive purpose of making burnt offerings , and from which he took a portable torch to carry to the mountain ? What is the relevance of usage of ' the fire'in Gen 22:6 ?

There is no need for a special fire here, any more then there is for special wood or a sacred knife. The crucial element is the sacrificial victim. The text is clear that Abraham loaded the wood for the fire on Isaac's back and that he carried "fire" with him on their climb. Some translators do say "firestone" instead of fire. In other words the "fire" was actually the means of making fire.
However, it more likely that he simply took fire with him, as nomadic people such as Abraham often did in the age before tinderboxes and matches - and many still do. Various suggestions have been given as to how Abraham could carry a portable fire:

a leather pouch or ram's horn a containing  a slow burning substance such as camel's dung

a bundle of sticks or punky wood

a torch topped with pitch

a small brazier




By saying, "the wood" it signifies that the wood for the offering was on the donkey, as it carried necessary items for what turned out to be a three-day trek to the land of Moriah. Two servants accompanied Abraham and Isaac. Food and water would certainly need to be carried by the donkey.
Now, God had spoken to Abraham before the journey began, so Abraham knew wood, a sharp knife, rope for binding, and fire would be necessary. As to whether he needed to take fire with him at the outset is not known. If he used flint or the method of rubbing two sticks together, that would only require fire to be started up once they got to the place. Maybe Abraham got sparks to ignite tinder before he and Isaac walked off together to the mountain. The text just does not say.
Neither does any text about Abraham suggest that he had "a fire burning in his tent for the exclusive purpose of making burnt offerings, and from which he took a portable torch". A bit of a problem with that idea might be the donkey balking at a flaming torch, or of violent wind or rain putting a flaming torch out. It is, however, unnecessary for grasping the significance of the event to attach any significance to "the" flame in the text. We only need to know that the flame for the sacrifice was in Abraham's hand as well as the knife, as he and Isaac headed off to the mountain, Isaac carrying the wood.

Thanks, Anne. Some say that in ancient times people used to cover the embers left over in kitchen with cheap salt so that they remained live the following day. The poor salt would eventually lose its character of saltiness and be thrown away ! It would be a good idea to keep different fires burning: one for cooking, another for heating the room and yet another for burnt offering. Just think of the Olympic Flame with the legacy attached to it !

@KadalikattJosephSibichan  That’s really interesting! Mind you, I think the origins of the Olympic flame were centuries before Christ, and were pagan. If not, someone might kindly put me right!

Thanks, Anne . Ex 27:20 says : And you shall command the sons of Israel that they bring you clear oil of beaten olives for the light, to make a lamp burn continually.  Well, Abraham lived much before Exodus, but nothing stopped him from keeping a lamp continuously burning in his house, to remind him of God's presence ! As for the  present world , during Easter Vigil Catholic Churches light a single Easter Lamp from which the faithful light their own candles .Catholic Churches housing the Holy Eucharist also have a lamp continuously burning before the Altar.

The Hebrew has הָ (ha) on fire, knife, burnt-offering, but not wood. It's not quite the same thing as the definite article in English - Gesenius' Hebrew Grammar (1909) relates it to a demonstrative pronoun and notes that it isn't needed for materials, giving the examples of fire or water.
But that isn't necessarily to say it's a marked addition, or especially significant to the meaning.
There is also הָאֵ֖שׁ at around 40 places in the OT, e.g. Exodus 13:22 (the pillar of fire) Leviticus 1:7 (the sons of Aaron the priest shall put fire on the altar). From this it can't be reconstructed a strict enough rule why the article's present - strict enough to define how we translate הָאֵ֖שׁ here in Genesis 22:6 and Genesis 22:7.
It's whether the article is significant enough to the meaning that the translation needs to address it (or paraphrase for it), or something that is quite neutral and dropped in for the metre/flow. Translation can't preserve every effect of every letter and for this passage even YLT doesn't attempt that.
Similarly, there are about 20 places where an article is on הָעֵץ, and again it would be disproportionate to survey for a pattern strong enough to bring back into the reading of Gen 22:6. Before that, we might try the simpler exercise of what would this verse have sounded like with an article added to wood or removed from fire.
I'll submit it's pleasing how it picks up the article on knife.
==
More tentatively, it might also be highlighting the presence of both an implicit and an explicit structure. The explicit structure marked by the article has:-
(He took) the offering  |  (He took) the fire and the knife  |  (They went) together
The implicit structure is marked by the objects-of-sense:-
(He took) wood and Isaac  |  (He took) the fire and the knife  |  (They went) together
If we distinguish Isaac from the burnt-offering, the verse gains aesthetic value, balancing as three pairs. (rather than a pair of threes)
==
The article on הָאֵ֖שׁ doesn't cast light on the practical logistics of where Abraham got the fire. The description of the scene leaves open to the reader to imagine it's conveniently available. לָקַח is neutrally "taking" something or picking it up or choosing or buying it - it's not a highly task-specific word emphasizing the effort to kindle a fire from scratch or carefully transfer it from a source.
Modern imagery of this scene might emphasize primitivity or find tragic parallels to a father-son great-outdoors camping trip: so a campfire necessarily outside the tent. But the contemporary reader/listener might perhaps have imagined something very portable in the technology of their own time. The Genesis author is perhaps careful to only say what he knows: Abraham took the fire.
